# Which to use in a research article: single-child or only child?

Tags: word-choice

I've seen both, and notice that only child is more common, but not sure which is better in an academic setting. Especially when it comes to the term "loss of single child"?

Comment: The context would need to be very specific for the two to be equivalent.  Consider: “The school was held hostage by a grizzly bear but miraculously the situation was resolved by a quick-thinking 6th grader and his revolver without the loss of a single child. “. Now swap in ***only***...

Comment: The ambiguity inherent in 'single child' is also shown in this example: 'To suffer the loss of a single child was tragic, to lose a second the same week was unbearable.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with "single child" as a synonym for "only child".

Looking through [the Google hits for "single child"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22single+child%22), they seem to fall into three groups:

- Ones that still make sense even if "single child" is not an idiom. For example, "a single-child family" means "a family with one child", just as "a three-child family" means "a family with three children".
- Ones that are clearly written by non-native speakers. For example, one page has "People say single child is not as smart, independent and finds it tough to adjust as those with siblings."
- Ones that *also* use the term "only child". This case is interesting, since these do at least seem to be examples of native speakers who use "single child" as an idiom; but even so, it suggests that they consider "only child" to be the usual phrase, and are merely using "single child" to avoid reusing the same phrase too often.

The same is not true of [the Google hits for "only child"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%only+child%22), which shows many examples of high-quality prose using "only child" as an idiom without also using "single child".

---

That said, in your specific example I would probably write "the loss of one's only child", which isn't actually using *either* idiom. But "the loss of an only child" (which *does* use the idiom "only child") is also perfectly fine.